# Overriding attach method from belongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to add an attribute on a pivot table on every attach/save in a  belongsToMany relationship.

Example:

```
// I don't want to do add the `rand` attribute everytime...
User::find(1)->roles()->save($role, ['rand' => rand()]);
User::find(7)->roles()->save($role, ['rand' => rand()]);
User::find(42)->roles()->save($role, ['rand' => rand()]);

// ... I just want to call save...
User::find(1)->roles()->save($role);
// ... and magically, `rand` attribute is set to rand()
```

I wanted to overload `belongsToMany` function in Model, but it does not look like to be a good solution, it looks like a hack. Because doing this, I have to create a new `BelongsToMany` class extending the original one, call the original `attach` method in `Model`, then override the returned object, and then my code becomes spaghetti, so I threw everything.

Is there any elegant way to do this?

*Side note: `rand` attribute is a stupid example, it's just an illustration, don't care about it.*

Comment: Are you using a pivot table for this relationship? And can we see it in your models?

Comment: Yes I'm using a pivot table. I have edited my question, thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried listening for the Eloqeunt event **creating** on the model and adding the attribute there https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events?

Comment: I want to update the pivot, not a model (unless I mistake, pivot has no model).

Comment: this package can help you https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-pivot (or you can get ideas from it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `saveRole` method in your `User` model

```
public function saveRole($role)
{
    $this->roles()->save($role, ['rand' => rand()]);
    return $this;
}
```

then just call

```
User::find(1)->saveRole($role);
```

I think it's much more easier and clean then overloading `BelongsToMany` class